# Selecting an input field on a newform.aspx path with Javascript without using jQuery

Tags: 2013, javascript, list-form

I'm looking for an object that contains the form field ids or something similar.

Something similar to the `_spPageContextInfo` object for form fields.

Anyone have an idea?

EDIT:
This code I'm using now is this:

```
function SiteRequestInitNewform() { 
    document.querySelectorAll('input[title="Title Required Field"]')[0].setAttribute('onblur', 'if (document.querySelectorAll(\'input[title="URL Name Required Field"]\')[0].value == ""){ document.querySelectorAll(\'input[title="URL Name Required Field"]\')[0].value = document.querySelectorAll(\'input[title="Title Required Field"]\')[0].value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "-"); }');
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("SiteRequestInitNewform");
```

But I'd like to have a fixed ID to get the field, the title attribute changes to easily.

Not to mention that this function is not supported < ie8

Comment: could you provide some example html?

Comment: Provided current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know there is no object that contains all form field id's. 
You can access all `form` `input`'s via something like `document.forms["form_name"].getElementsByTagName("input");` and afterwards check the objects for your `input`.

When your problem is, that the id is prefixed (i.e. `ctl00_ctl52_ShellNewsfeed`) you could simply check if the id ends with the id (or simply set the `ClientIdMode`to `static`).

You could also use a similar selector like `document.querySelectorAll('input[id=*"YourIdEndsWith"]')` to get all elements which id's are ending with your `input`'s id.

Comment: Okay, I guesse I'll just keep using the querySelectorAll for now. Thanks!